# custom User model with auto_now_add=True causes "non-editable field" Exception in UserAdmin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm learning python Django. I have created a custom user model and it is working, but whenever I visit any user's profile through the Django admin I get this error:

```
Exception Value:    
'date_joined' cannot be specified for UserProfile model form as it is a non-editable field. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserAdminModel.
```

This is my custom UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ A model for authors and readers."""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'password']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    objects = UserProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I am using the default Django AdminModel:

```
class UserAdminModel(UserAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: Pls show the relevant model parts. Which `django.auth` base model do you subclass?

Comment: I have updated it. you can now see my model and it's serialiser. let me also add the model Manager

Comment: Please show us the admin form

Comment: Neither the manager nor serializer are relevant here; the thing you need to show is `class UserAdminModel`, as the error states.

Comment: But this error is not coming from your REST API. It's coming from the Django admin. You *do* have that class, probably in your admin.py.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Django Admin site expects the `date_joined` field to be editable - but your custom user model does not allow that - because `auto_now_add` always sets the current date.

This behavior is known & [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

> As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True
>   will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

1. Either you make the change explicit, by telling Django it is indeed [not meant to be editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```py
class UserAdminModel(UserAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ["date_joined"]
```

2. Or revert your change, going back to the Django default of having that field editable:

```py
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # [..]
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**You *probably* want to go the second route.** I have not checked if any of the other fields you have overridden in your custom user model are incompatible with the Django default admin. If you make changes, make them meaningful enough to warrant the extra work of updating the relevant forms or admin views.

Comment: I have used the default=timezone.now, may be I still need to learn more about arguments to be passed to model fields

Comment: Use the `timezone` from `django.utils` and not from standard `datetime` package. And `now` is amethod:
`from django.utils import timezone`, `default=timezone.now()
`