# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'date' cannot be specified for Forum model form as it is a non-editable field

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py

```
# Create your models here.
class Forum(models.Model):
    publisher = models.CharField('Публикатор', max_length=50, default='Anonymous')
    topic = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField('Текст')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.CharField('Комментарий', max_length=100, default='Комментарий')
    # slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default='default')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic
```

How to solve such problem, I also tried set editable=True. It didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom User model with auto\_now\_add=True causes "non-editable field" Exception in UserAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249404/custom-user-model-with-auto-now-add-true-causes-non-editable-field-exception-i)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with

```
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here, you set it to `auto_now_add=True`, it will add current date time automatically but cannot edit later. Try it to replace with

```
from django.utils import timezone

date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

The following is from doc[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

> DateField.auto_now_add¶
> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored. If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of auto_now_add=True:
>
> For DateField: default=date.today - from datetime.date.today() For
> DateTimeField: default=timezone.now - from django.utils.timezone.now()

Comment: it says now:
NameError: name 'timezone' is not defined

Comment: it worked, thanks.
But why auto_now_add didn't work I don't get it.

Comment: did you check out the quote in my answer that i copied from django doc? It says that the field is used for generating timestamp, cannot be modified...

Comment: So, today we need set timezone even if in the past it was correct to set auto_now_add=True.
I am saying that because in the video that i saw people actually set auto_now_add=True.
Sorry that i don't get it

Comment: timezone.now() and autO_now_add both will add current time when you generate it. the key difference is that timezone.now() is set to default. means that if you do not do anything, it will use current time, however, this can be changed later if you want to. auto_now_add=True will not allow you edit later.